# In Julia, what is the type of an anonymous function when an outer scope is involved?

Tags: julia, anonymous-function

I can create an anonymous function within a list comprehension in Julia. I expect that this would create a type of `Vector{Function}`. Instead, the type is something like `Vector{var"#2#4"}`.

For example, when involving an outer scope with an anonymous function

```
typeof(x->x) <: Function  # true

a = 1
typeof(x-> x + a) <: Function  # false
```

while

```
f(x) = x
typeof(f) <: Function  # true

a = 1
g(x) = x + a
typeof(g) <: Function  # true
```

Why is the anonymous function typed differently than the regular function when the outer scope is involved?

Now, in a list comprehension:

```
typeof([x->x, x->x]) <: AbstractVector{Function}  # true
```

```
typeof([x->x+i for i in 1:2]) <: AbstractVector{Function}  # false
```

```
typeof([x->x for i in 1:2]) <: AbstractVector{Function}  # false
```

whether or not the index `i` is involved. I initially expected `true` in each case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that your initial example is not correct, as you have:

```
julia> typeof(x->x) <: Function  # true
true

julia>

julia> a = 1
1

julia> typeof(x-> x + a) <: Function
true
```

So both anonymous functions have a type that is a subtype of `Function`.

Now as for comprehension note that this is mostly unrelated with the presence of parameter, as you have:

```
julia> typeof([x->x, x->x]) <: AbstractVector{Function}
true

julia> typeof([x->x]) <: AbstractVector{Function}
false

julia> typeof([x->x for i in 1:2]) <: AbstractVector{Function}
false
```

The reason for this behavior is when you write something like `[...]` then Julia picks a narrow element type of the comprehension (if it did not try to do so you would have `Any` element type - the behavior that Python have for its standard lists).

So now how to solve your issue.

To make sure that comprehension has element type of `Function` you need to write:

```
julia> typeof(Function[x->x]) <: AbstractVector{Function}
true

julia> typeof(Function[x->x for i in 1:2]) <: AbstractVector{Function}
true
```

See also [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#man-comprehensions) and [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#man-array-literals) in the manual where it explains how element type for a result of a comprehension and an array literal is picked.

If you omit the `Function` prefix the element type is narrower, and in this case the proper subtyping condition would be as follows:

```
julia> typeof([x->x]) <: AbstractVector{<:Function}
true

julia> typeof([x->x for i in 1:2]) <: AbstractVector{<:Function}
true
```

(note the extra `<:`).

This behavior is related to the fact that in Julia such parametric types are *invariant*, which is explained [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#man-parametric-composite-types) in the Julia manual.